# How to convert Scala Array to Java List ?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I want to convert an `Scala` array to `Java` list.

`val legends = Array("0-500", "500-1000", "1000-2000", "2000-3000", "3000+")`

to Java List.

Comment: Scala.Collections.JavaComvertors

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Same way you would convert a java array to a list (scala arrays are the same as java, so no surprise there):

`java.util.Arrays.asList(legends:_*)`

`:_*` is called a `splat`. It is needed to tell the compiler that you want to pass elements of the array as separate varags parameters, not the whole array as one parameter.

Or you can do it explicitly:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val javaList = legends.toList.asJava
```

Or implicitly:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val javaList: java.util.List[String] = legends.toList
```